# what is the smallest value of the side of the regular hexagon below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Inside a regular hexagon $ABCDEF$ mark a point $P$ such that $AP=a$, $PC=b$ and the measure of the $\angle APC = \angle AFD$. Calculate the smallest value of $EF$.(Answer: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$)

My progress:
Draw the figure we have
[image]

$\triangle  APC: a^2+b^2 =AC^2 \implies AC = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} = DF$

$\triangle FEG:cos30^o = \frac{FG}{L} \implies \frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2L}\\
\therefore L =\frac{\sqrt3\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{3}  $

but what would be the condition to have the value of the minimum side?

Comment: The value you got is actually smaller than the supposed minimum.. it seems to me that the given data fixes everything. Can you check the statement again?

Comment: @GReyes  I always transcribe the exact copy of the problem...it could be an error in the book's answer

Comment: Since your angle $APC$ is right and $a$, $b$ are given, $AC$ is uniquely determined, so the size of the hexagon is uniquely determined. This is very strange. On the other hand your computation seems correct and you get a smaller value than the one in the answer...

Comment: To get a minimum there must be a variable - what is the variable?